# Is there a way to tag or name volume instances using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using docker compose, I find a lot of volume instances:

```
› docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               4a34b9a352a459171137aac4c046a83f61e6e325b1df4b67dc2ddda8439a6427
local               6ce3e52ea363441b2c9d4b04c26b283d8b4cf631a137987da88db812a9a2d223
local               a7af289b29c833510f2201647266001e4746e206128dc63313fe894821fa044d
local               fb09475f75fe943671a4e73d76c09c27a4f592b8ddf62224fc4b20afa0095809
```

I'd like to tag or name them, then reuse them if possible rather recreating them each time.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are anonymous container volumes that happen when you define a volume without a name or bind it to a host folder. This may be with the `VOLUME` definition in your Dockerfile, a `docker run -v /dir ...` rather than `name:/dir`, or a volumes entry in your docker-compose.yml with only the directory. An example of a compose file that does a named mount is:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  my-vol:
    driver: local

services: 
  my-container:
    image: my-image
    volumes:
      - my-vol:/container/path
```

Once the anonymous volume has been created, there's no easy way to rename it. Easiest solution is to mount the anonymous volume along with the your target named volume and do a copy, e.g.:

```
docker run -v 123456789:/source -v my-vol:/target --rm \
  busybox cp -av /source/. /target/
```

Where 123456789 is the long name of your anonymous volume.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to use a named volume mount when the service volume will be outside of the project directory (ex: ../dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data) or is the project directory root (ex: ./app)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but paths to a host volume (bind mount) inside of docke-compose may be relative or absolute. Relative can have a `./path:/container/dir`, or even a `../parent-sub-folder:/container-dir`. And absolute looks like `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.

Comment: Right, I'm able to mount the volume (relatively or absolutely). But how do I name it when it's mounted like so: `../my-volume:/container/path`

Comment: Host volumes (bind mounts) don't get named at all, they completely bypass the volume management and get mounted directly into the container. There is a 'local-persist' plugin you can add to docker to create named volumes for local directories.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.